# BreezingForms unique user email validation problem

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, validation

I've created a form using BreezingForms(free). Before submitting the form I'm checking if the entered email address is unique using the "Before submit" field in my form settings. The code I am using is :

```
$this->execPieceByName('ff_InitLib');

$email = '\'' . ff_getSubmit('email_test') . '\''; 
$value = ff_selectValue('SELECT * FROM kvkfr_users WHERE email= ' . "$email");

if($value != ''){
echo "<script> alert('Email is not unique'); </script>";
exit();
}
```

My code runs as expected and if a duplicate email address is found I am getting the "Email is not unique" alert, but after that my page refreshes and I get a blank white page.I just want to stop the submitting process without refreshing the page(if possible). What should I use instead of `exit()` to stop the submitting process and stay on the page?

PS. Should I use `ff_selectValue()` or Joomlas database object to execute my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to achieve the wanted functionality! Here is how: [crosstec forums](https://crosstec.org/en/forums/35-form-help/121605-unique-email-server-validation.html)